# Use virtual constructor to reset to initial state

Tags: delphi, constructor, virtual

i do not have any experience with virtual constructors which are available in Delphi. I consider to use virtual ctors in a class hierachy to reset the instance to an initial state like this:

```
A = class
end;
B = class(A)
end;
C = class(B)
end;

FooA = class
    a_ : A;
    constructor Create(inst : A); overload;
    constructor Create; overload; virtual; abstract;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Bar : A;
end;

FooB = class(FooA)
    b_ : B;
    constructor Create; override;
    constructor Create(inst : B); overload;
end;

FooC = class(FooB)
// ...
end;

{ FooA }
constructor FooA.Create(inst: A);
begin
    inherited Create;
    a_ := inst;
end;

destructor FooA.Destroy;
begin
    FreeAndNil(a_);
    inherited;
end;

function FooA.Bar : A;
begin
    Result := a_;
    a_ := nil;

    // here comes the magic
    Self.Create;
end;

{ FooB }
constructor FooB.Create;
begin
    b_ := B.Create;
    inherited Create(b_);
end;

constructor FooB.Create(inst: B);
begin
    inherited Create(inst);
    b_ := inst;
end;
{ FooC } // ...

var
    fc : FooA;
    baz : A;
begin
    fc := FooC.Create;
    baz := fc.Bar;
    WriteLn(baz.ClassName);
    FreeAndNil(baz);
    FreeAndNil(fc);
    ReadLn;
end.
```

Are there any problems/pitfalls in this design? The simple example works like a charm but i feel a little bit uneasy calling constructors (which do not construct anything) like this.

Edit:

I decided to move the initialization to a method in protected area with a meaningful name, what makes me feel better ;-)

```
FooA = class
strict private
    a_ : A;
strict protected
    procedure SetInst; overload; virtual; abstract;
    procedure SetInst(i : A); overload;
public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Foo : A;
end;
```

Comment: Why don't you just rename your "create" to something like "procedure Reset; virtual;" and call it everywhere? This way you can be sure it's doing exactly what you want.

Comment: @himself Maybe the code above does exactly what i want without any problems and without any new methods. But maybe not... ?

Comment: Your code is overloaded with **foo**s, consider using **bar** and **baz** :-)

Comment: I would say that when you call Self.Create, you create a new instance, because "Create" is a class method, not an object method. But I can be wrong here. Anyway, in cases where the code is hardly obvious it's better to evade the case at all. At least to make life easier for maintainers.

Comment: The call to Self.Create seems not to create a new instance (no leaks in the example), but you are right: Maybe it's better to give the method a name which makes clear what happens, instead of writing fancy designs that work but nobody understand.

Comment: @himself: Self.Create will not create a new instance of whatever class you're in, it simply re-runs the constructor, and it returns Self (the same Self). This allows one to daisy-chain constructors. In other words, an Delphi constructor works like a class method when called on a class (ie: TSomething.Create) and works like any other function when called with an instance (ie: Self.Create)

Comment: @hansmaad: Would you mind explaining the "design" in a few words (not lines of code)? All I see is an experiment with virtual methods and constructors. You can't talk about "design" without understanding the problem it's supposed to solve.

Comment: It is a kind of 'chain of responsibility'. FooC checks if the current action is specific to C and performs it on its C instance, or deligates to the inherited FooB, which checks if it is specific to B and so on... After the bar process has finshed, the instance (here C) is returned. On the next call of bar a new C instance will be created by FooC and passed to all ancestors.

Comment: Why do you think you need a virtual constructor?

Comment: BTW, in `constructor FooB.Create;` instead of doing `b_ := B.Create;` use `b_ := Self;` or even `Create(Self);` (without any assignment) which won't cause a 2nd instance to be created AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very few classes are written to support the use of constructors as re-initializers. They usually assume that any dynamically allocated memory has *not* already been allocated. If you're in control of all the classes you're using, then go ahead and carefully use constructors as re-initializers.

Even if you're in control, I'd still advise against it. **It's not idiomatic Delphi**; anyone else reading your code (perhaps even you, a few weeks or months from now) will be confused — at least at first — by your non-standard use of constructors. It's not worth the trouble. If calling the `Bar` function is supposed to release ownership of the `A` object and create a new instance, then write functions with names that make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

Rob's right about this being really weird-looking code that's likely to confuse people, and moving your code to an initialization routine is a good idea.  In case you were wondering, the main purpose of virtual constructors is for something completely different: to more easily support "factory" style object creation.

Some outside source provides some data that can identify any descendant of a base class, and the factory uses a class reference and calls a virtual constructor defined in the base class on it. That way you end up with an instance of the descendant class without having to hard-code knowledge of the descendant class into the factory code.

If this sounds a bit strange, take a look at a DFM file.  It's got a list of form objects that descend from TComponent, with their published properties.  When the form reading code comes across an `object` statement, it reads the class name, looks it up in a table that maps class names to class references, and calls the virtual `TComponent.Create` on that class reference.  This calls the virtual constructor for the actual class, and it ends up with an instance of that type of component, and starts to fill in its properties.